# can i use any database in ionic framework with visual studio 2015

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

i'm a beginner developer of ionic framework Please let me know how we can connect any database to Ionic android app in visual studio 2015

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: "connect any database" , if you mean locally within app then use http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn921897.aspx 
 this link can help you with the issue, for the first time i used Firebase an online database ,